# Order by conditioned to a field

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I would like to change the order by clause in function of a field, but I don't know whether it's possible or not.

Here is an example:

```
**TABLE DISCOUNTS**
category    offer
A           0
B           0
C           1
D           1
F           0

product_id  category    price
       1      A         100
       2      B         300
       3      C         250
       4      C         150
       5      D         200
       6      B         200
       7      F         250
```

I'm willing to select all the products but already ordered, firstly if they are an offer or not (I want to show offers first), and after that I want to group them by category and sorted by price.

The problem is with the offers, here is not important to group by category because won't be too many offers and makes more sense to directly show them sorted by price.

So here is the ouput I'm getting:

```
product_id  category    price       offer
4            C          150         1
3            C          250         1
5            D          200         1
1            A          100         0
6            B          200         0
7            F          250         0
2            B          300         0
```

While I would like to get a different order (sorting offers only by price):

```
product_id  category    price       offer
4            C          150         1
5            D          200         1
3            C          250         1
1            A          100         0
6            B          200         0
2            B          300         0
7            F          250         0
```

The query I'm using is:

```
select * from Products p
left join Discounts d on p.category = d.category
order by offer desc, p.category, price
```

and here is the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41dee/1)

What would be the best option here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it you want offers ordered by price only and non offers order by category then price. In that case you can use an `IF` to conditionally order:

```
select * from Products p
left join Discounts d on p.category = d.category
order by offer desc,IF(offer,price,p.category), p.category, price
```

Comment: wow, that looks nice and works with the fiddle. Could you explain that IF please? I don't understand it.

Comment: @vivoconunxino Certainly. It simply says "If offer is true, sort by price. Otherwise sort by category".

Comment: @vivoconunxino Exactly `IF(condition,then,else)`

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need to remove `category` from the `order by`:

```
select *
from Products p left join
     Discounts d
     on p.category = d.category
order by offer desc,
         (case when offer = 0 then category end),
         price ;
```

Comment: If I remove category, they wont be grouped by category when they're not an offer

Comment: that, or add p.category at the end of the group by `order by offer desc, price, p.category`

Comment: (Don't use evil SELECT *)

Comment: Updated the fiddle and the question, If I remove category the product_id 7 falls  between the category B

Comment: @vivoconunxino . . . I see, you want a conditional for the category.