# Why is the use of wildcard * in select statements discouraged?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've been advised in this self page to not use the wildcard `*` in my SQL queries.

Wrong query

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

instead of

```
SELECT field_a, field_b, field_c FROM table
```

I understand only one reason, if you need to know only 3 fields from that query there is no point in force the sql engine to work with all the fields and send them back to your program if you just want to use a few.

But this makes me doubt if is correct to use it if you need all (or almost all) the field data retrieved, or even in those cases it's better to specify all your fields.

Is there any other reason to avoid wildcards than reducing the amount of data sent from the DB engine to the program?

Comment: Where exactly did you find this advice ?

Comment: mmm, recently, let me search for it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456975/order-by-conditioned-to-a-field  in Gordon's answer comments

Comment: Did you notice [who](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) was writing an answer with `select *` ? Do you really think he would have written it if `select *` was so obviously evil ? In most cases you don't use `select *` because it's unclear but it's not "evil".

Comment: Don't know why that Strawberry said don't use Select *. It's fine if you want all fields. If you don't then obviously you just select what you need.

Comment: wildcard is widely used. I would only consider avoiding it if you have large amount of rows and columns but only want to look at a few columns. For your case it should be fine.

Comment: I'd be tempted to close this question as *"coming from baseless FUD"*

Comment: @DenysI found other example: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147273/confusion-about-proper-use-of-wildcard-in-sql

Comment: I see this question has been put on hold... I didn't want opinions, I wanted reasons, technical reasons regarding if the use of a concrete kind of queries (and very often used) have technical aspects which can affect performance or security..  I want to remark this, and I really think this is an interesting question (despite the fact it can be basic or not) for the main purpose of Stack Overflow and this is what the answers gave to the question, no one argued or showed different opinions. Whatever happens, thanks again for the users who took their time responding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason which you have understood is very much valid and is perhaps the most strong reason why it is said so.

In many of the application where the table contains too many columns(lets say 20) and the table size is also huge containing millions of records and if you want to retrieve only specific column then there is no point of using wildcard * as then the MYSQL engine has to unnecessarily iterate though all the columns and all the rows.

But to make a point **it is nothing like that `*` is discouraged** infact it can be a boon in the same situation when you have 20 columns and you want to retrieve the values from all the columns.

To add more to it the * could be slower because of the floowing reasons:

- In your table you dont create index on all of your columns and the query uses full table scan. So it makes the query slow.
- When you want to return trailing fields from table which contain variable length columns and hence can result in a slight searching overhead.

Comment: Please note that the question is about when all columns are required.

Comment: @DenysSéguret:- I tried to explain it with an example. Hope that makes it clear or do you want me to add more explanation?

Comment: If you have 200 columns in your table, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @JanDvorak:- Yes I agree I just took a random value.

Comment: How the fact that you don't index all columns could induce a slow `select *` ? (answer: it can't)

Comment: If `select *` is slow due to a full table scan, listing the columns won't help you with that.

Comment: @DenysSéguret:- I am just considering a situation where lets say I am trying to use *, and it returned more columns than what I actually needed, the server would often have to perform more expensive methods to retrieve data than it otherwise might. Do correct me if I am ona wrong path.

Comment: @RahulTripathi full table scan = every row of a table is read in turn. You are talking about reading every column, which is not the same thing. And most likely the engine has to read every column even if it doesn't transmit them.

Comment: @Denys I took my time to explain it, It's not when all columns are required, never told that. It's just if it involves any negative aspect more than the one I pointed out.

Comment: Somewhat useful information: when you explicitly specify all columns instead of wildcard, you can add an aliases for each column. This can be helpful when selecting data from joined tables that might have columns with identical names.

Answer (score 4):

Using `*` means you're querying **all** the table's fields. If that's what your application is supposed to do, it makes sense to use it.

If that's not what your application is **supposed** to do, it's a potential recipe for trouble. If the table is ever modified in the future, the best case scenario is that your application will be querying columns it doesn't need, which may harm performance. The worst case scenario is that it will just break.

Comment: Please note that the question is about when all columns are required.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'm not sure I got my distinction across. Say the table has three columns, and the application needs all of them. Does this mean it needs columns A, B and C, or **all the columns**? Right now, there is no difference, but if a fourth column would be added in the future, would the application want to query it? If the answer is yes, by all means, `*` should be used. If it is no, `*` should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all others that it's not "evil" per se, but I do try and avoid it because of the specific design pattern that I follow. Generally after designing tables, I then create views and join together relevant tables. Finally, I create stored procedures which then select from the views.

I have found that it is problematic (at least in SQL Server) to use wildcard selects in the views and stored procedures. Everything looks good at first, but it breaks down after new fields are added to the source tables.  It corrupts the views, and they must then rebuilt to be fixed. Based on the size of the system, this can be a problem.

Since wildcard selects in views cause corrupted views after the source tables are altered, I have started avoiding wildcard selects and will manually alter views after adding new columns to tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a specific reason except following two which are also considered as efficient and optimized method to write query.

1. You might not need all fields with query so its better to get only required fields will be reduce system load to run query and data will be fetched much faster.
2. Sometimes we have fields with weird name like lcf_user_email_response which we dont want to use while getting data and showing it on site so to make field alias we use field name not the wildcard.

using field name gives us more freedom to play with fields and output

but there is no such restriction or bad with with wildcard, use them if you need all fields.